# Android Studio invalid authentication data. Cannot assign requested address: connect

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I have a Issue where I can't login to GitHub anymore.

All worked fine just a moment ago, then suddenly my Flutter Build stopped to work. When I wanted to check out a different branch to check if my changes are the problem I was asked for my GitHub Login Info, which was odd because the Token hasn't expired yet. Anyway I generated a new Token and got the following error:

> Invalid authentication data. Cannot assign requested address: connect

[image]

Now I suspect that somehow my JAVA installation is at fault, so installed a freshly downloaded JAVA version. To no success.

The reason why I suspected JAVA is the error when building is also JAVA related. I only found one thread that talked about that problem and it suggested to kill oll JAVA related apps in the Taskmanager, of which I have none. And a reboot of the Computer also didn't help. This error also persists after the fresh install of JAVA.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
*
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:263)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:255)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:108)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:95)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:41)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:49)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:115)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:144)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:98)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:212)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:275)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:247)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:240)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.bindInternal(DatagramChannelImpl.java:1194)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.bind(DatagramChannelImpl.java:1164)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.DatagramSocketAdaptor.bind(DatagramSocketAdaptor.java:107)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.createDelegate(DatagramSocket.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:330)
    at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:389)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:49)
    ... 34 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**--- Edit ---**

I can't believe it. I just closed NordVPN and everything works again. Anyone has an idea what Nord does to make all JAVA stuff to stop working? And also why did it suddenly crash JAVA, I am using Nord for a long time, and this never happened before...

Comment: I just want to say that you saved my day! Same problem here and it was NordVPN messing things up! But why? :(

Comment: Were you using Windows 11? I've had similar strange and frustrating issues where Android Studio can't connect to the internet since switching to this OS

Comment: Moin Cody,

I think I was using Windows 11, but I am not sure. I am using Windows 11 now, though. And I haven't had any issues with Android Studio since, even the error I described above no longer exists.

But I suggest, you check other Apps on your computer, to make sure, they are not causing the issues. Even Apps you think shouldn't be an issue. Like in my case, I never thought NordVPN might cause problems with other Apps like this.

Answer (score 0):

I was ultimately able to solve the issue in Android Studio by going into File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> Enable "Use credential helper" checkbox.